# Web php load so slow after long time (30 minutes) no use at Chrome

Tags: php, web

I am having 1 problem with php web. My web using php 7.0 and httpd at Linux ubuntu.

When I browser the web at localhost, it working file. But after I deployed. The first request is ok. but if I not request the web long time, about 30 minutes. It take very long time to response. When I see at chrome console, it display pending.

After I waiting loading, ~ 1 minutes. The next requests are fine, very fast

I checked the code, nothing big query.

Here is my php config

Could you please help to give me some suggestions, thanks so much!

Comment: You need to carefully profile your code to figure out where the slowdown is coming from but it sounds like there might be suspended services that need to be woken up, though none comes to mind right now that would affect PHP.

Comment: One of the most common reasons for slow web page loading is problems with database access. For example wrong user login information or large database tables

Comment: I checked all code, I not detect any suspended service. And also no problem with my database :(

Comment: Thanks @NadirLatif. I checked database, all databases work fine :(

Comment: Look for errors in frontend code and backend code. The web developer toolbox console shows Javascript errors. The error log files of web servers will show errors in backend code. Also try clearing the web browser's cache.